# Use igraph with bigmemory in R

Tags: r, igraph, r-bigmemory

I am not able to read bigmemory object in igraph in R

```
    class(mcalls)
    [1] "big.matrix"
    attr(,"package")
    [1] "bigmemory"
    callGraph <- graph.data.frame(mcalls)
    Error in graph.data.frame(mcalls) : 
    the data frame should contain at least two columns
```

Is there anyway to read big.matrix datatype in igraph?

Comment: you should make a reproducible example. How does your matrix looks? Is it an adjacency or edges matrix? and the most important how large is your graph : "A graph with one million vertices and ten million edges needs about 320 Mbytes"?

Comment: It is a edges matrix.Currently i am trying on small file so size is not a issue.

Comment: you should make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to get an answer.